# Matlab: how to export "date time" data to an external file? "Error using fprintf. Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs."

Tags: matlab, file-io, printf

I'm running Matlab 2016a and I'm a bit of a newbie.

I imported certain columns of data from a very large external .txt file.  The first column is "date time."  When I print it to screen, this is how it appears:

```
'2019-07-10 20:00:00'
```

The other imported columns all consist of numbers.  I want to print only the columns I imported to a .txt file.  For the columns of numbers, this works:

```
fileID = fopen('fag_1.txt','w'); fprintf(fileID,'%f\n',fag_1); fclose(fileID);
```

However, I have tried all afternoon and can't find a way to print the date time column.  For example, this is a solution that worked for someone at a forum:

```
fileID = fopen('DT.txt','w'); fprintf(fileID, '%23s\n', DT); fclose(fileID);
```

It gave me this error (which is similar to the error I get for all the other methods I have tried):

```
Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Error in XXX (line 230)
fileID = fopen('DT.txt','w'); fprintf(fileID, '%23s\n', DT); fclose(fileID);
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to deal with this?  Thank you.

---

***Reply to Paolo***
The text file is huge, Paolo, so I will only show the first four columns on the first row.  Please feel free to let me know if that is insufficient.  I would be interested to know how to do this in Matlab so it would be great if you could help!  Thanks very much.

```
DT  MOD UNMOD   PRESS
2015-07-01 00:00:00 -999.0  -999.0  -999.0
```

Comment: Can you show a small snippet of your .txt file?

Comment: @Paolo, thanks for your interest. I have added a small snippet at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to figure out how to do it in Matlab, but found a different solution here at Stackoverflow that uses awk (below).

```
awk '{print $1}' test.txt > test2.txt
```

This doesn't really answer my question, but it solves my problem!  If anyone has an opinion on whether to mark my question as answered or delete it, it would be great to know.  I don't want to leave it open, as that deters people who like to answer questions from those who have a record of choosing an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using matlab to extract a few columns from a text file is like using your car to drive one city block. You can do it, but it will take a lot of extra work and resources (money, gas), and there are much better tools for the job (walk, ride your bike). In this case, **awk** is a good choice. It is designed specifically for this type of task and it works well.

However, the direct answer to your Matlab question is exactly what the error message says: you are trying to give `fprintf` a cell to print, and `fprintf` cannot print cells.  For example, make a text file that consists of four lines of the sample data from your question ("2015-07-01 00:00:00 -999.0  -999.0  -999.0"). If you import this file and look at the result in Matlab, we see:

```
>> fin = fopen('sline.txt','r');
>> sin = textscan(fin,'%s %s %f %f %f')

sin =

  1×5 cell array

{4×1 cell}    {4×1 cell}    {4×1 double}    {4×1 double}    {4×1 double}

>> fclose(fin);
```

We can see that the imported data has been placed in [cells](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html). If you want to reference the items inside the cells (in this case, the strings, so they can be printed), use {}. For example:

```
fout2 = fopen('sout2.txt','w');    
for k=1:4
    fprintf(fout2,'%s %s %f %f %f\n',sin{1,1}{k},sin{1,2}{k},sin{1,3}(k),sin{1,4}(k),sin{1,5}(k))
end
fclose(fout2);
```

So you can do it Matlab, but it takes eight lines of ugly code.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This is very helpful.  Thanks particularly for your advice on Awk.